# Unexpected token error for .send_keys in selenium web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm relatively new to python, so please forgive any cases of rookie errors...
I've been following a tutorial to build an instagram web scraping bot, and I can't seem to solve this particular error. It happens for the command `.send_keys` in `.send_keys(username)` and `.send_keys(password)`. The error I get is: `unexpected token 'send_keys'Python(parser-16)`

This also creates an issue for the `self` underneath which receives the warning: `Undefined variable: 'self'Python(undefined-variable)`. This issue resolves itself when I comment out the token error.

I don't know if this is due to indents or what but I've followed the tutorial exactly and his works seamlessly

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")
            .send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")
            .send_keys(password)


InstaBot('nomadsvalley', '*******')
```

If anyone could help that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: I've tried and it working for me. if you add a sleep(X) after the last command you will se before the browser closes, that the user and password are written correctly

Comment: @pcampana after which command, specifically? It doesn't seem to make any changes to the error.

Comment: I'm just saing that I could not reproduce the error. Adding `sleep(10)` after `InstaBot('nomadsvalley', '*******')`, and you will see if username and password and correctly filled

Comment: @pcampana don't worry I figured it out. didn't have \ at the ends of find_element commands. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer working solution :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait

class bot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

    def intagramLogin(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("username")
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("username")
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Log In')]"))).click()

        driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = bot()
    bot.intagramLogin()
```

Output:

[image]